# javascript obj.value is disappearing later in the function

Tags: javascript, object, scope

Here is a javascript function, which works fine as shown:

```
function loopput(obj,id) {
     alert(' id is ' +id + ' obj.value ' + obj.value);
     var q = obj.value;

    document.getElementById(id).value = obj.value;
    obj.selectedIndex = 0;

    if(id == 'InputType') {
    alert('below inputtype q is ' + q + ' obj.value ' + obj.value);
       if (q != 'select'){
          document.getElementById('SubType').value = 'N';}
       else {
          document.getElementById('SubType').value = '1';}
   }//id = inputtype
  }//end loopput
```

However, if I use obj.value instead of q in the statement

```
 if (q != 'select')
```

i.e.

```
 if(obj.value != 'select')//my original approach
```

it does not work.  The reason is that obj.value is coming up blank, although it was fine in the first alert.

I suspect there is some kind of scoping problem here, but I don't understand what it is.  Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Setting `obj.selectedIndex` changes the value of a `select` element. `q` has a copy of the value, hence it's not changed.

Comment: That is so true -- and I didn't see it.  I can easily put obj.selectedIndex at the bottom of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Between assigning the value to `q` and testing `q != 'select'` you have this line:

```
obj.selectedIndex = 0;
```

… which changes the selected `<option>` to a different one which has a **different value** thus changing the value of `obj.value`.